# Why is this simple scroll event animation so janky?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to recreate a sticky position element that is anchored to the left-hand side of the page as you scroll. I can't use `position: fixed` as the element needs to move with y-axis (i.e. it's only locked on the x-axis). I am seeing an unreasonable level of jank for the simplest of scroll events:

[image: Janky Scroll]

I'd like to use the upcoming `position: sticky` but browser support is not at a point where I am happy to use this. Can anyone explain why this is so janky? Please see the following example which uses the same positioning of the `left` style property to achieve the same effect, but without any jank (I've included the element inspector just to prove that it is indeed the `left` positioning that is being tweaked!):

[image: No Janky Scroll]

I've also explored using `transform: translateX(..)` but this still results in the same issue. Here's the code for the first GIF:

```js
var sticky = document.getElementById("sticky");

var update = function() {
  sticky.style.left = window.scrollX + "px";
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', update);
```

```css
body {
  width: 4000px;
}
#sticky {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="sticky">
  I'm janky
</div>
```

And the CodePen for the above: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBWgQg.

I've taken a dive into the JavaScript on the second example and I can confirm it's not using `requestAnimationFrame()` – it's just a simple jQuery line:

```
$(elem).css('left', e.currentTarget.scrollLeft)
```

Is anyone able to explain why mine is so janky yet the other example is not?

Comment: Just want to comment that on the latest Chrome in macOS (2015 iMac), your CodePen runs with no lag on a 1080p external monitor, but is slightly janky (like your GIF) on the iMac's 4K/retina screen. Definitely seems like some kind of performance issue.

Comment: @JonUleis – Yeah, something isn't quite right somewhere. I've spent two nights on this problem now and haven't managed to get any further. What I don't understand is why the second example is really smooth, when it's working in pretty much exactly the same way... Have tested in Chrome, Firefox and Safari – the issue is present in all three (in macOS 10.12 / MacBook Pro 2015).

Comment: @JonUleis – just to update, I *think* this is related to macOS / OS X's elastic / smooth scrolling. Scrolling with the scrollbar itself, or even scrolling whilst the cursor is simply hovered on the scrollbar actually resolved the issue. It's only janky when two-finger scrolling on a trackpad...!